# What happens exactly, in terms of reputation, when a flag I raised is accepted?

Tags: discussion, flags, reputation

If I flag something and my flag is accepted, does it somehow affect my reputation?
If not, is there a good reason why it shouldn't?

Comment: Accepted flags *do not* affect your rep.

Comment: It doesn't affect rep, it helps keep the site clean. And you gradually get higher number of flags per day, which can be up to a maximum of 100 per day per user.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing happens. Flags do not affect your own reputation.

Flags marked as helpful do influence [how many flags you can use in a day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185888/on-the-recent-changes-to-flagging-and-limits/185890#185890), and can earn you badges ([Deputy for 80](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1002/deputy) and [Marshal for 500](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal)).

Flags serve to help moderate the site, see [A Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/). As such, they serve an entirely different purpose. Reputation gives you privileges to moderate, moderation should not then give you rep.

Answer (score 9):

> does it somehow affect my reputation?

No.

> is there a good reason why it shouldn't?

Reputation comes from good (helpful) answers/questions, that's it. Flags serve a different purpose. Just like editing, reviewing, etc., they are used to keep the site clean.

Comment: Of course, editing *does* give you rep (up to a certain amount). And reviewing indirectly gives you rep (up to that same amount), in that reviewing is a great way to find questions/answers that often need editing. ;)

Comment: @neminem touche on the rep from editing(to a certain point) but your argument for reviewing attributing to rep is weak :P

Comment: Not *that* weak - it's why I *personally* still get excited about reviewing the First Posts queue, even though I have all the badges I can get out of reviewing that queue, directly.